# printing using a for loop in cgi

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm attempting to print fields in a form depending on the iteration using CGI. Is it possible to nest a for loop within a CGI print statement like so? I keep getting a syntax error on the for loop line...

```
print $survey->Tr(
            $survey-td(
                $survey->startform(name=>'survey', method => 'POST', action => 'survey.cgi'),
                for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++){
                    $survey->hidden(name=>"q$i", value => "currentQ[q$i]"),
                    $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Previous'),
                    $survey->endform(),
                }
                $survey->startform(name=>'survey', method=>'POST', action=>'survey.pl.cgi'),
                $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Next'),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: `s/$survey-td/$survey->td/` ?

Comment: «`Tr`» ⇒ «`tr`». «`-td`» ⇒ «`->td`». «`$i=0;`» ⇒ «`my $i=0;`». «`for (my $i=0; $i < $size; $i++);`» ⇒ «`for my $i (0..$size-1);`». The first `startform` needs to be in the loop. The last `startform` needs a matching `endform`.

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Instead you should push all the items on to an array (in advance of creating the parent element) and then pass the array as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda. You can embed a `for` using `do`:

```
print $survey->tr(
   $survey->td(
      do {
         my @forms;
         for my $i (0..$size-1) {
            push @forms, $survey->form(
               { name=>'survey', method => 'POST', action => 'survey.cgi' },
               $survey->hidden(name=>"q$_", value => "currentQ[q$_]"),
               $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Previous'),
            );
         }
         @forms
      },
      $survey->form(
          { name=>'survey', method=>'POST', action=>'survey.pl.cgi' },
          $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Next'),
      ),
   ),
);
```

It's probably easier to precompute the inner parts, though.

```
my @forms;
for my $i (0..$size-1) {
   push @forms, $survey->form(
      { name=>'survey', method => 'POST', action => 'survey.cgi' },
      $survey->hidden(name=>"q$i", value => "currentQ[q$i]"),
      $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Previous'),
   );
}

push @forms, $survey->form(
   { name=>'survey', method=>'POST', action=>'survey.pl.cgi' },
   $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Next'),
);

print $survey->tr( $survey->td( @forms ) );
```

If you really do want to have `for` in the middle, you could use `startXXX` and `endXXX`.

```
print $survey->starttr();
print    $survey->starttd();
for my $i (0..$size-1) {
print       $survey->form(
               { name=>'survey', method => 'POST', action => 'survey.cgi' },
               $survey->hidden(name=>"q$i", value => "currentQ[q$i]"),
               $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Previous'),
            );
}
print       $survey->form(
                { name=>'survey', method=>'POST', action=>'survey.pl.cgi' },
                $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Next'),
            );
print    $survey->endtd();
print $survey->endtr();
```

Finally, `map` neatly combines `do` `for`.

```
print $survey->tr(
   $survey->td(
      ( map {
         $survey->form(
            { name=>'survey', method => 'POST', action => 'survey.cgi' },
            $survey->hidden(name=>"q$_", value => "currentQ[q$_]"),
            $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Previous'),
         );
      } 0..$size-1 ),
      $survey->form(
          { name=>'survey', method=>'POST', action=>'survey.pl.cgi' },
          $survey->submit(name=>'direction', value =>'Next'),
      ),
   ),
);
```